# copy information from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, merge

I have an output dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

After summing the values in the “Flux” column and a couple other analyses I get an output that looks like this. This is a summarized version of the original dataframe.

[image]

I need the new output to include the “Treatment” column in from the first output. So that the final dataframe has three columns: ID, Total_CO2, Treatment Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please don't use screen-shots to present output. Present your code and input/output as text using the Stack Overflow code formatting facilities. Also, your problem would probably be best solved at the aggregation step.

Comment: or `merge(flux, total_C)[c('ID', Total_CO2', 'Treatment')]`

Comment: `merge`followed by `unique` seems to do the trick. Thanks @rawr